# edge case for selecting a checked radio input with jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, validation

I have a problem selecting a checked radio button with jquery. The radio buttons are generated by a function from a MVC that i'd rather not change and its name is like `id[number]`.
Simply put, I have to check if any of these buttons are checked:

`<``input type="radio" name="id[1]" value="1"/>`

`<``input type="radio" name="id[1]" value="2"/>`

The problem is that `jQuery('input:radio[name=id[1]]:checked').val()` will select some function from the jQuery library.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you put the parentheses after val?  When I've seen "some function from the jQuery library" showing up as a result, it's generally because I put "val" instead of "val()".

Comment: no words can adequately describe how ashamed i am for making such a mistake...

thank you!

Comment: I've done it before myself (which is why I recognized the symptoms).  There's something about val() that feels more like a property than a method, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

u don't need the `id[1]` to be put that way... 
all you need is `id`...

as each `name="id"` can be put multiple times on a radio type.

and it will return the value of the checked radio or NULL if none selected.

```
<input type="radio" name="id" value="1"/>

<input type="radio" name="id" value="2"/>

jQuery('input:radio[name=id]:checked').val();
```

or

```
jQuery('input:radio[name="id"]:checked').val();
```

note: the " quotes on the second one if the first does not work

**Edited:** or better yet try and put the `id[1]` in quotes... as im unfamiliar with MVC
so you end up with :

```
jQuery('input:radio[name="id[1]"]:checked').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to see if any are checked, use `.length` like this:

```
if($(":radio[name='id[1]']:checked").length) {
   //1 is checked
}
```

`.length` is how many are matched, and `0` ~= `false` in javascript :)